# vba mapping function behaving unexpectedly

Tags: arrays, string, vba, ms-word

why the function below works sometimes and fails at others?

**The function idea**

- a string gets passed to this function by a user or a procedure
- the string will be split by *multiple delimiters* into an array of words
- each word is cleaned from non-letter characters except for the characters (dash and single quote mark inside the word) an example of words having these two char. would be (man's spirit, life-loving)
- if the single quote marks are found surrounding the word, they get trimmed too
- after processing each word in the string, and if the word is not empty it gets stored into the array ***Along with*** it's ***starting position and end position***
- the start and end positions refer to the position of that word ***within*** the ***input string*** and excluding any non-letter characters that might surround the word.

Here's the code

```
Sub test()
        Dim d$: d = ThisDocument.Range.Text
        Dim Arr(), i&
        Arr = ExtractWordsFromDoc_2(d)
        For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
            ThisDocument.Range(Arr(i)(1) - 1, Arr(i)(2)).HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
        Next
    End Sub


Function ExtractWordsFromDoc_2(ByRef doc As Document, Optional ByVal Delimiters)
'   Take a string, and return it as a one dimensional array of individual arrys, each array
'   has three values (single delimited string, start range of delimited str, end range of delimited str)
'   the input string is delimited by any of several characters. None of those characters are returned in
'   the result. Provide a default list of Delimiters, which Should come from registry.
'   But allow override.
'===================================================================================================================
    Dim InputString$: InputString = doc.Range.Text
    'return an array of empty string when input string is empty
    If InputString = "" Then
        ExtractWordsFromDoc_2 = Array("", 0, 0)
        Exit Function
    End If
    '===================================================================================================================
    Dim DelimitList As Variant, ArrayOfWords() As Variant, TmpArr() As Variant
    Dim OneChar$, TempWord$, WordCount&, InputStringLength&, CharIndex&, ArrUbound&
    '===================================================================================================================
    'if delimiters are missing, We should get these from a Registry
    If IsMissing(Delimiters) Then
        DelimitList = Chr(34) & Chr(147) & Chr(148) & Chr(32) & "," & "." & vbCr & vbTab & "/" & "!" & "|" & ";" & ")" & "(" & "?"
        'Chr(34)= straight double quotes mark
        'Chr(147) & Chr(148) =opening and closing double quotes marks
        'Chr(32) = space
    Else
        DelimitList = Delimiters   'user can override if needed
    End If
    '===================================================================================================================
    InputStringLength = Len(InputString)    'get the input string length
    For CharIndex = 1 To InputStringLength    'loop through each character
        OneChar = VBA.Strings.Mid(InputString, CharIndex, 1)    'Read one character at a time
        Select Case InStr(DelimitList, OneChar)    'Test if the character is a delimiter character
        Case 0    'it is not a delimiter
            TempWord = TempWord & OneChar    'Add the character to the current word
        Case Is <> 0, Is = InputStringLength    'it is a delimiter or it is the last character
            'if the temp word is not empty and not a quotation mark
            If TempWord > "" And Not (TempWord = "'" Or TempWord = Chr(145) Or TempWord = Chr(146)) Then
                TmpArr = TrimSingQuotes(TempWord)    'send that word to be cleaned from single quotaion mark
                If (Not TmpArr(0) = "") Then    'if the returned word has length, count it
                    WordCount = WordCount + 1
                    ArrUbound = WordCount - 1  'set the new upper dimension for the storing array
                    ReDim Preserve ArrayOfWords(ArrUbound)    'expand storing array when we have a cleaned word with length
                    'Save new word in the last place inside the array, along with the word start and end ranges
                    ArrayOfWords(ArrUbound) = Array(TmpArr(0), _
                                                    CharIndex - Len(TempWord) + TmpArr(1) - 1, _
                                                    CharIndex - Len(TempWord) + TmpArr(2) - 1)
                End If
                TempWord = ""    'reset the Temp Word
            End If
        End Select
    Next CharIndex
'===================================================================================================================
    ExtractWordsFromDoc_2 = ArrayOfWords    'Return the storing array through function name
    'do some cleaning
    Erase ArrayOfWords
    Erase TmpArr
End Function

Sub testTrimSingQuotes()
    TrimSingQuotes (Empty)
End Sub

Function TrimSingQuotes(ByVal TempWord$)
'SSQP =starting single quote position
'ESQP = ending single quote position
'==================================================================
    If TempWord = "" Then
        TrimSingQuotes = Array("", 0, 0)
        Exit Function
    End If
    '==================================================================
    Dim SSQP&: SSQP = 1
    Dim ESQP&: ESQP = Len(TempWord)
    '==================================================================
    'trim starting single quotes
    Do While (Mid(TempWord, SSQP, 1) = "'" Or Mid(TempWord, SSQP, 1) = Chr(145) Or Mid(TempWord, SSQP, 1) = Chr(146)) And SSQP < ESQP
        SSQP = SSQP + 1
    Loop
    '==================================================================
    'trim ending single quotes
    Do While (Mid(TempWord, ESQP, 1) = "'" Or Mid(TempWord, ESQP, 1) = Chr(145) Or Mid(TempWord, ESQP, 1) = Chr(146)) And (ESQP > SSQP)
        ESQP = ESQP - 1
    Loop
    '==================================================================
    'get the trimmed word
    TempWord = Mid(TempWord, SSQP, ESQP - SSQP + 1)
    '==================================================================
    'test the trimmed word for output
    If TempWord > "" And Not (TempWord = "'" Or TempWord = Chr(145) Or TempWord = Chr(146)) Then
        TrimSingQuotes = Array(TempWord, SSQP, ESQP)
    Else
        TrimSingQuotes = Array("", 0, 0)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: When you say "the string will be split by multiple delimiters" do you mean to say that a given string could potentially contain more than one delimiter or just one per string?

Comment: Do you need Word ranges or starting and ending positions in the body text.  These are frequently 2 different ordinals.

Comment: Do you need to support Unicode, or just ANSI?

Comment: @CindyMeister As it currently stands, this question wouldn't survive Code Review. It works for one case but not for another, violating the first question of CR: "Does your code work as intended?". What this question needs is some clean-up, not a migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I didn't spend a lot of time (i.e. none) figuring out why your code isn't working as intended. I suspect it has something to do with calculating your position in the input string.

It is *much* simpler to leverage the build in `Split` function to do your heavy lifting, and probably much more performant than relying on the string functions like `Instr` and `Mid`.  Note that this relies on 2 quirks of the `Split` function:

First, if you call `Split` on an empty string, it returns an array with a `UBound` of -1.

Second, VBA's version of `Split` doesn't remove empty entries - so, `Split("foo", "foo")` results in the array { vbNullString, vbNullString }. This is good, because you can tell by the result how many delimiters were in the string based on the size of the resulting array (number of delimiters in the input will always equal the number of array elements minus one.  In VBA terms, `delimiterCount = UBound(Split(inputString, delimiter))`.

Your requirement makes this easy in that your delimiters are all 1 character.

Try something like this:

```
Private Function MultiSplit(inValue As String, delimiters() As Variant) As Variant()
    Dim output() As Variant

    Dim bound As Long
    ReDim Preserve output(bound)

    Dim tokens() As String
    Dim index As Long

    tokens = Split(inValue, delimiters(0))
    If UBound(tokens) = -1 Then
        MultiSplit = Array(vbNullString, 0, 0)
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Process each delimiter.
    For index = 1 To UBound(delimiters)
        tokens = SubSplit(tokens, CStr(delimiters(index)))
    Next index

    Dim position As Long
    For index = LBound(tokens) To UBound(tokens)
        If tokens(index) = vbNullString Then
            'This means a delimiter was removed, so increment the position to account for it.
            position = position + 1
        Else
            'Resize the output array and write the result for the remaining token.
            ReDim Preserve output(bound)
            output(bound) = Array(tokens(index), position, position + Len(tokens(index)) - 1)
            position = position + Len(tokens(index)) + 1
            bound = bound + 1
        End If
    Next index

    MultiSplit = output
End Function

Private Function SubSplit(inValue() As String, delimiter As String) As String()
    Dim tokens() As String
    Dim substring As Variant
    Dim token As Variant
    Dim output() As String

    output = Split(vbNullString)
    For Each substring In inValue
        tokens = Split(substring, delimiter)
        'Test for an empty token - these need to be preserved in the output.
        If UBound(tokens) = -1 Then
            ReDim Preserve output(UBound(output) + 1)
        Else
            For Each token In tokens
                ReDim Preserve output(UBound(output) + 1)
                output(UBound(output)) = token
            Next token
        End If
    Next substring

    SubSplit = output
End Function
```

Test code:

```
Private Function TestCode()
    Dim delims() As Variant
    Dim results() As Variant
    Dim test As String

    delims = Array(Chr(34), Chr(147), Chr(148), Chr(32), ",", ".", vbCr, vbTab, "/", "!", "|", ";", ")", "(", "?")
    test = "foo|||bar,,baz?crux"
    results = MultiSplit(test, delims)

    Dim result As Variant
    For Each result In results
        Debug.Print result(0) & vbTab & result(1) & vbTab & result(2)
    Next result
End Function
```

Note that I didn't examine the existing code even far enough to determine if your output positions were 1 or 0 based.  The example above is 0 based.  If you need 1 based, insert `position = 1` after `Dim position As Long`.

Quote removal is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @Ali_R4v3n - You might have to add a pre-processing step to handle "delimiters" that aren't really delimiters. If you have `'` in your delimiter list but want to ignore contractions, that's more of a linguistic problem than a string handling problem.